# Laravel authentication with google is not working with guard

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, laravel-authentication, laravel-guard

I have been working with a Laravel project with multiple guard authentications. one of my guard name is 'customer'. Only customers are allowed to login with their Google Account. Previously I was using Laravel default Users Model as Customer account and it was working fine while login with Google account. Now in order to make my Customer account separate I had created a new Customer Model and shifted all my things to that model. Everything is working fine but while login with Google account it's creating a new customer row with all data but not logging in to the dashboard. I am using middleware for customers. Since its not logging in the middleware is preventing to access the dashboard. Here is my codes below. let me know if anyone can help.

**Customer Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasFactory;
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','google_id','linkedin_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Customer Migration File**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->text('password');
            $table->text('phone')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->text('address')->nullable();
            $table->integer('shipments')->nullable();
            $table->integer('balance')->nullable();
            $table->integer('due')->nullable();
            $table->string('google_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('linkedin_id')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

**config/Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
       
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
        
    ],

'providers' => [
       
        'customers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
        ],

    ],

'passwords' => [
       
        'customers' => [
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
      
    ],
```

**GoogleController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Customer\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
use Exception;
use App\Models\Customer;


class GoogleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
      
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback()
    {
        try {
    
            $customer = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
     
            $finduser = Customer::where('google_id', $customer->id)->first();
     
            if($finduser){
     
                Auth::login($finduser);
    
                return redirect('/customer/dashboard');
     
            }else{
                $newUser = Customer::create([
                    'name' => $customer->name,
                    'email' => $customer->email,
                    'google_id'=> $customer->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('123456dummy')
                ]);
                
                Auth::login($newUser);
     
                return redirect('/customer/dashboard');
            }
    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/auth/google', [App\Http\Controllers\Customer\Auth\GoogleController::class, 'redirectToGoogle']);
Route::get('/auth/google/callback', [App\Http\Controllers\Customer\Auth\GoogleController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);

Route::get('/dashboard',[App\Http\Controllers\Customer\DashboardController::class,'index'])->middleware('customer')->name('dashboard');
```

I think the problem is with GoogleController

```
Auth::login($finduser);
Auth::login($newUser);
```

**The above codes are not working.** Can anybody help me out >?

Updates : Middleware codes are added below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Customer
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::guard('customer')->check()){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/customer/login')->with('error',"You must login to access Customer Panel");
    }
}
```

Comment: is `customer` set as the default guard? and you are not showing your middleware

Comment: Hello , i have updated my question and added the middleware codes

Comment: is `customer` your default guard?

Comment: no. default guard is sill user i didnt change anything to there . i have just added extra customer guard

Comment: then `Auth::login(...)` is not using the `customer` guard ... you have to tell it what guard to use or it will use the default

Comment: Exactly Auth:login is not not working i also know that but i dont know how to tell it with guard. Can you please tell me what will i have to do to use customer as a guard instead of default guard while Auth:login

Comment: you are already doing that in the other places you are using `Auth` ... what do you think `Auth::guard(...)` is doing  :)

Comment: I have tried with Auth::guard('customer')::login($user); but not working

Comment: `Auth::guard('customer')->login(...)`   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: Wo ! It worked . I was exactly looking for this line. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks to @lagbox The problem is solved ,**
[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Wrong : `Auth::login($newUser);`

Right : `Auth::guard('customer')->login($newUser);`